# Sytem locale doesnt retrieved at jvm startyup

Tags: macos, jvm, locale

After changing my system locale (region and currency), i expected to be able to use the newly defined value in my java programs.
But after running a small exemple the currency still use the old value.

Is there something special to do in macosx to change the locale everywhere??

Answer (score 0):

For some reason java on OS X doesn't just pick up the system locale. I think you'll just have to set it manually for java.

I don't use Java much, but I've set the encoding before using the command line argument `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`. I'm not sure about how to set other aspects of the locale such as the currency symbol, but maybe that will start you on the right track.